# How to open line app by using click on call in line app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, outsystems

I am opening LINE app from my native Android app and my requirement is, i need to open line app by clicking mobile number and it will call the clicked mobile number.

I used "tell:number" it worked to call on mobile call contact but for line app I don't know how to implement so anyone's know help me to solve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to LINE documentations, you should use LINE URL scheme (`https://line.me/R/`) as your base url and follow their instruction on how to use it in various ways by adding parameters.

Source:
https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/line-login/using-line-url-scheme/